# Deploying Solana onchain programs In Java

Tags: solana-program, java

Can we create onchain programs in Java Programming Language In Solana? I have been studying about it and saw Rust, C and C++ languages. Can we do it in Java?

Answer (score 4):

At this time the primary onchain program languages are Rust and C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

On Solana, smart contacts cannot be written using onchain programs. Currently, only C and Rust are supported.

However, you may submit transactions by utilising the Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview)

> Solana on-chain programs are compiled via the LLVM compiler
> infrastructure to an Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) containing a
> variation of the Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) bytecode.
>
> Because Solana uses the LLVM compiler infrastructure, a program may be
> written in any programming language that can target the LLVM's BPF
> backend. Solana currently supports writing programs in Rust and C/C++.
>
> BPF provides an efficient instruction set that can be executed in an
> interpreted virtual machine or as efficient just-in-time compiled
> native instructions.